# Find the value of k

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

Find the value of k if

$(3x + k)^3 + (4x - 7)^2$ has a remainder of $33$ when divided by $x-3$

Should I split up the main equation: $(3x + k)^3 + (4x - 7)^2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $P(x)$ be your polynomial. Then $P(3)=33$.

**Remark:** We are using the **Remainder Theorem**, which is entirely different from the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

The Remainder Theorem says that if $P(x)$ is a polynomial, then the remainder when you divide $P(x)$ by $x-a$ is $P(a)$.

The proof is straightforward. Let $P(x)=(x-a)Q(x0+r$. Put $x=a$. The $(x-a0Q(x)$ part dies, and we get $r=P(a)$.

Comment: Yeah I know. So it begins like this: $(3x + k)^3 + (4x - 7)^2 = 33$ where I should substitute 3 in the equation?

Comment: Yes, you should write $(9+k)^3+5^2=33$, which gives $(9+k)^3=8$, $9+k=2$, $k=-7$.

Comment: alright thanks. :)

Comment: You are welcome. I added some information about the Remainder Theorem to the answer.

Comment: yup. thanks for that too. :)